# RDS Connection to Python Using SQLalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy

I'd like to start out by saying I am very much a student and a noob.  I've been struggling to create a connection from our AWS RDS Database.  It is the host for our ML model in Jupyter Notebook.  Attempting to use SQLalchemy as the connector.

Trying to utilize variables if possible to create the connection, and use getpass for security.

I've imported the following dependencies for the project:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base`
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session`
from sqlalchemy import create_engine`
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError`
from getpass import getpass`
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
```

This is my code to connect:

```
secret = getpass('Enter the secret value: ')

engine = create_engine(
    host="anonymousendpoint.amazonaws.com",
    port='5432',
    database="DBname",
    user="Project",
    password="secret"
)

engine.connect()
```

Have tried including url='postgres' in the args above, and a few other variations.  I get the following error the most: `TypeError: create_engine() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'`

Sometimes this error: `ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'postgres'`

It is prompting for the password, so I know it is at least running through the code. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You are missing the url positional argument, and since it's postgresql, providing `'postgresql:///'` may work, e.g. `create_engine("postgresql:///", ...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it , i hope helpfully

```
conf ={
    'host':"anonymousendpoint.amazonaws.com",
    'port':'5432',
    'database':"DBname",
    'user':"Project",
    'password':"secret"
}
engine = create_engine("postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}".format(**conf))
```

> postgresql+DBApi(asyncpg,psycopg,pg800 ,...)

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Still giving me issues unfortunately.  Now saying OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "anonymous.rds.amazonaws.com" (54.215.28.5), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
connection to server at "anonymous.rds.amazonaws.com" (54.215.28.5), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres."  ."  Password is correct and all alphabetic characters. Database is public and active.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the previous answer was almost correct but the reason for the error was that the user must again be specified after the port instead of the database.  In AWS, the Endpoint string that you use for host contains the database name.

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql://{username}:{password}@{endpoint}:5432/{username}")
```

Once done, you could then work with the engine object like this:

```
sql = """
select * from {table}
"""
pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine)
```

You obviously can put whatever you wish for SQL.  For simple SQL, you can just put it in a single line eg. 'select * from {table}' but using the triple quotes, you can put in extremely complex sql statements well formatted with spaces & indents.